# Access files inside workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, selenium-webdriver

I have a **spring web project** which basically Test webApp and capture screenshot of pages. The path of the saved image looks something like below:

```
"\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
 \Demo\WEB-INF\Results\Test\1118015800\error\error_ST001_1.jpg"
```

I am trying to display the saved image on a JSP page and so far success has been elusive. I tried different combination of relative path also I tried to give absolute path but it doesn't work. My image tag looks something like this

```
<img src="<c:url value="/WEB-INF/Results/Test/1118015800/error/error_ST001_1.jpg" />" />
```

Does anyone have any idea on displaying the image? Could it be because files are stored inside the .metadata folder of Eclipse workspace that I am not able to display any image?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `WEB-INF` directory is special.  The web container won't serve files from that location - that behavior is defined in the Servlet Spec.

You can either create a servlet that takes requests from the client, loads images (e.g. using `getResourceAsStream()`) and streams them back, or move the images to a different place in your web app hierarchy.

Comment: Hey ! the problem was with the resource mapping. I didn't know you could totally do like this  <resources mapping="/screenshots/**" location="/WEB-INF/" > and it did work. Thanks again for help...